# Why "text-align: right" doesn't work on empty contenteditable element in Firefox?

Tags: css, html, firefox, contenteditable, text-align

Consider the following: [(Live Demo)](http://jsbin.com/oxurar/1/edit)

HTML:

```html
<div contenteditable></div>
```

CSS:

```css
div {
  text-align: right;
}
```

When you click the `div` **in Firefox**, the cursor is located at the left (looks like `text-align: right;` has no effect). But, if you start typing, `text-align: right;` starts taking effect.

Why is that? Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: That cant be chagned, the cursor always starts on the left

Comment: @Doorknob, Which Firefox version do you use?

Comment: A long shot, but try adding `="true"` at the end to `contenteditable`. The example in the Firefox docs uses that syntax.

Comment: @Doorknob, It doesn't work for me in Firefox 21.0.

Comment: I have v20.0 and I see the same problem.

Comment: Just installed the latest (v21.0) and the problem is still here. By the way, with how jsbin works, it seems to remember that you typed something in the div, so once you have (and the cursor was to the right), it will still be to the right after you change the HTML and click again. However, if you _don't_ type anything into the div, you will see that adding `="true"` doesn't help.

Comment: Looks like a bug in Firefox - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1103011

Answer (score 6):

This can be achieved using a simple change like this:

```
<div contenteditable>&nbsp;</div>
```

We're forcing a blank space in it.

Well if the space matters, I think you have a problem. But I hope this helps :)